# Change position of UI Dialog jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery post request on a change in drop down event which renders a form just below the drop down, this all is done in [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) 
The rendered form is just a bit long, user has to scroll down to save it. I don't want the user to scroll down, the position should go up a little,maybe by a 20px.

```
    $("#dropdownid").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 1)
    {

        $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/controller/model/'; ?>",$(this).serialize(),
            function(data) {
                $("#dialog").html(data);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            }
        );
    }
});
```

The form is already in the center so ideally this would not work [Change the position of a jquery dialog box after it loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024132/change-the-position-of-a-jquery-dialog-box-after-it-loads) posted by another user.

Answer (score 2):

There are some options and also for the position of the dialog. Have a look: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

This would set the dialog in center and 150px to top. Just try:

```
$("#dialog").html(data);
$("#dialog").dialog({ position: [($(window).width() / 2) - (dialogWidth / 2), 150] });
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
```

Comment: Nope. It did not move at all tried making a large vale till 750,but doesn't move at all. What wrong could I possibly do here.

Comment: You should add the line before you open the dialog. And i've edited the answer.

Comment: When I inspect element over the UI dialog there's a top parameter of which when I change the value the position is affected, do you know how can I change that through my code of jQuery.

Comment: I found this other question.. Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304830/jqueryui-dialog-positioning

Comment: You can change the position value with the "css" function: http://api.jquery.com/css/ but i'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Nope. No luck. I don't think jQuery ui-dialog entertains .css property

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What is working for me is next combination:

```js
 $(function () {
  var _left = (window.innerWidth / 2) - 250;
  $("#dv_TreePopup").dialog({
   autoOpen: false, width: 500, height: 'auto',
   position: [_left, 50],
   create: function (event) {
    $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'absolute', "left": _left, "top": 50 });
   }
  });
      $("#dv_TreePopup").dialog("open");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="position: relative;">
 <div id="dv_TreePopup" style="display: none;">
        Some content
    </div>
  
</div>
```